# JQuery requires 2 clicks instead of 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

I'm populating values in a div based on clicks to buttons on the page, but it's requiring 2 clicks for the value to change. The first part is populating the calloutAmt and calloutAmtdouble spans with the values that appear on page load, then the next part should change them based on the button clicked, but it takes two clicks to do so.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $("#calloutAmt").text(selectAmt);
  $("#calloutAmtdouble").text(selectAmt * 2);

  $("div.donation-level-container").on("click", function() {
    $("#calloutAmt").text(selectAmt);
    $("#calloutAmtdouble").text(selectAmt * 2);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="matchcallout">Your gift of $<span id="calloutAmt"></span> will be DOUBLED to do $<span id="calloutAmtdouble"></span> worth of good! </div>
```

Comment: What is `selectAmt`?

Comment: It's a variable that pulls the value of the $$ values you have to pick from on the page. I didnt include all the other jquery on the page since those elements are working on the page as expected, in this instance i just can't get past the 2 click issue.

Comment: Here is the page - please don't judge the cobbled together code, this has been worked on over time by too many developers. The line directly under the buttons should change as you select different amounts but it is only working with 2 clicks. http://give.childrensmercy.org/site/Donation2?df_id=3861&mfc_pref=T&3861.donation=form1

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can't comment, because I don't have the required reputation.

That being said, nothing in your code allows us to determine issue. You would have to post the full code to get that.

BUT it seems obvious that this is working as expected and that your issue is going to lie in the setting of the variable selectAmt, which is still undefined or '' or whatever first time you click button, then gets generated by ajax or whatever.

Thus, second time you click, the variable has already been populated by the first round and is ready to be inserted into the dom. One way to check if this is indeed issue is to change the value of selectAmt between clicks and see if the value always lags one click behind of expected value. In theory, what you would want to do is set the text in the span not on click of button, but after the calculation or however selectAmt gets populated.

Hope this helps.

--edit--
Add a console.log(selectAmt) inside of the on click function... in theory, this will be empty first click but not second, confirming my mentioned suspicions above.